# VBA not looping through entire data

Tags: vba, loops

The code stops at line 160. I need it to run through the entire list till the last populated cell

```
Dim mrow As Long, Arow As Long, iRows As Long, srow As String
Dim x As Long, y As Long, i As Long
Dim AG_Label As String, AG_val As String, SNL_val As String, SNL_Label As     String, M_Label As String, Rng As Range
Dim Vval As Long, Speriod As String, aperiod As String
Dim M_Match_1


Arow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Arow
    AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(j, "N").Value
    mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To mrow
        M_Match_1 = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "P").Value
        M_Label = Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "C").Value
        If AG_Label = M_Label And Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "L").Value = "FRY-9C" Then
            Sheets("Mappings").Cells(j, "J").copy
            Sheets("AG").Cells(Rows.count, "AM").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                On Error Resume Next
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is line 160?

Comment: Does it throw an error if you remove the `On Error Resume Next` line?  You say it stops at line 160 - number of ways to interpret that.  You've only got about 16 lines of code, so it'll never reach line 160.  Or do you mean row 160 on the spreadsheet? Is row 160 the last line with data?

Comment: Amend as follows: `Arow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Sheets("AG").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` `mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Sheets("Mappings").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` `Sheets("AG").Cells(Sheets("AG").Rows.count, "AM")...` you've got the point?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes. runtime error 13

Comment: @Tehscript Now the code does not run

Comment: Which line did the error occur on and what was the value of the variables on that line?  Also you _should_ add `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module - that will point out you haven't declared the variable `j`.

Comment: @Tehscript is trying to say that `Arow = Sheets("AG").Range("A" & Sheets("AG").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` should be one line, `mrow = Sheets("Mappings").Range("A" & Sheets("Mappings").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row` is another line.  Although it will only make a difference if you have a 2003 file and a 2007+ file open (`Rows.Count` will count the rows on the currently active sheet if you don't specify the sheet.  If you're working in 2003 but have a 2007+ sheet active it will return more rows than are available in the 2003 workbook).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the error is that it does not paste the value on every single occurance. only the first

Comment: @Tehscript the code only populates the output values of the If statement of the first instance and not for all others

Comment: That's not an error - that's the code not doing what you expect it to do, but somewhere in the code it gives error code 13 which is a data type mismatch - trying to assign a letter to a numeric variable for example.  From what you've said it appears to be skipping some of the loops - have you tested the value of `mRow` & `aRow`?  If you're sheet is blank it will return a number less than 2 - so your loop may be doing something like `For j=2 to 1`

Comment: Have just noticed that at this line:  `AG_Label = Sheets("AG").Cells(j, "N").Value` you haven't set a value for `j` yet so it will be 0 and you're trying to get the value of the cell `N0` which doesn't exist.

Comment: FWIW (because your later question shows that you have fixed it since this question), your `Sheets("AG").Cells(Rows.count, "AM").PasteSpecial` was pasting the value to cell AM1048576 all the time.